# How to compile multi-line python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make Tk window like python console. But my problem is when multiline code comes. How i can `compille_command()` and `runcode()` if input is multiline: for example if True:print(something) or for i in range(x)

```
from tkinter import *
import code,skuska

class Display:

    def __init__(self):

        self.frame = Tk()
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.frame,text="DoIt", command=self.vypis)
        self.button.pack()
        self.output = Text(self.frame)
        self.output.pack()

        self.konzola = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
        self.out = skuska.Capturing()


    def vypis(self):

        compiledText = self.kompiluj(self.entry.get())
        with skuska.Capturing() as self.out:
            self.konzola.runcode(compiledText)

        self.output.insert(END,str(self.out)+'\n')
        print('OUTPUT IS :' , self.out)


    def kompiluj(self,kod):
        return code.compile_command(kod)

    def loop(self):
        self.frame.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
Display().loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use the interactive interpreter code for this. You can use the [`exec()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to interpret Python code.

Under the hood, that is exactly what `code.runcode()` *does*.